# BASH Getting output on the same line

Tags: bash

I have a raid setup and I would like to match the Device ID with the Mounted Drive. Thankfully the outputs are the same 0-15. The following commands I am using is:

```
MegaCli -LdpdInfo -a0 | awk '/Target Id:/ {print $3}'

MegaCli -LdpdInfo -a0 | awk '/Device Id:/ {print $3}'

lsscsi | awk '/MR9260-16i/ {print $6}'
```

I was working on a simple script that started with one put and worked, then I added the second output which didn't work but added the results after the first output like so:

```
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
/dev/sdg
/dev/sdh
/dev/sdi
/dev/sdj
/dev/sdk
/dev/sdl
/dev/sdm
/dev/sdn
/dev/sdo
/dev/sdp
/dev/sdq
/dev/sdr: 104
113
210
211
212
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
223
224
225
226
```

And I was like "Crap... that didn't work" anyways here is my script

```
# Prints the Device ID of each drive on the Raid Controller.
perform_target() {
    MegaCli -LdpdInfo -a0 | awk '/Device Id:/ {print $3}'
}

# Prints each mounted drive out that is on the Raid Card.
perform_drive() {
    lsscsi | awk '/MR9260-16i/ {print $6}'
}
    printf ' %s\n' "$(perform_drive)" "$(perform_target)";
```

Comment: You will probably find you get a better answer if you show the output from your MegaCli and lsscsi commands and explain what you are trying to achieve rather than telling us what doesn't work...

Comment: @Mark What i am trying to achieve is to have the outputs be on the same line like:

/dev/sdb 104
/dev/sdc 113
etc, etc. 

This will match what mount is with what Device ID. Without doing a lot of research and manual work. Then later this info can be used to test SAS drives with hdparm, DD and Smartctl (requires DeciveID and Mount to work), hours and wiping. 

It's  a small project that will lead into a bigger project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two columns in separate files, you can use `paste` to join them:

```
$ cat file1
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd

$ cat file2
104
113
210

$ paste file1 file2
/dev/sdb        104
/dev/sdc        113
/dev/sdd        210
```

Comment: one-liner for original questioner's scenario would then be `paste <(perform_drive) <(perform_target)`

Comment: This seems to work and thank you both ThatOtherGuy and ArtemB

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to invoke MegaCli twice:

```
MegaCli -LdpdInfo -a0 | awk <<'EOF'
  /Target Id:/ {printf("%s: ", $3)}
  /Device Id:/ {print $3}
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you, that will make things simple as this script because more complex later down the road.

Comment: I found this to work a little better `MegaCli -LdpdInfo -a0 | awk '/Target Id:/ {printf("%s  ", $3)} /Device Id:/ {print $3}'`